# Regex: Equivalent expression without using positive lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split `4d6/2d6/1d6` matching `/`. However, in order to split it I need to have specifically `\d` preceding `/` and another `\d|d` succeeding `/`, so other expressions like `1d6+db/2` don't get split. I've come to the solution of using positive lookbehind, but I need my regex to be valid in IOS systems too. The solution I've come up with is `/(?<=\d)\/(?=\d|d)/g`. Is there a way to create an equivalent to this expression without using positive lookbehind?

Comment: Try matching with `(?:\/|^)(.*?\d)(?=\/\d|$)`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/AJsiBV/1).

Comment: It did work, but the resulting array is filled with empty strings between the matched elements. The result: `(7) ['', '4d6', '', '2d6', '', '1d6', '']`. The same happens with `1d6+db/2`, look: `(3) ['', '1d6+db/2', '']`

Comment: _"and another `\d|d` succeeding `/`"_ Did you mean `\dd` instead of `\d|d`? Or perhaps just `\d`? Since you're not making use of the `d` in your pattern at all.

Comment: I said **matching**, not splitting. `Array.from(text.match(/(?:\/|^)(.*?\d)(?=\/\d|$)/g), x => x[1])`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put it. But yes, I need `\d|d` as a safety measure.

Comment: @Alyssa You realize that `\d|d` will match "1" or "d", not "1d", right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I used match and it returned me a very weird array. Look: `(2) ['4d6', '4d6', index: 0, input: '4d6/2d6/1d6', groups: undefined]`. The same happened with `1d6+db/2`: `(2) ['1d6+db/2', '1d6+db/2', index: 0, input: '1d6+db/2', groups: undefined]`.

Comment: @41686d6564 yes, I know that.

Comment: You are not using what I suggested. You omitted the `g` flag.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I haven't noticed that. I used `g` flag and the output got better: `(3) ['4d6', '/2d6', '/1d6']`, but I don't want the `/` to be included in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an *extracting*, *matching* approach rather than splitting:

```
/(?:\/|^)(.*?\d)(?=\/\d|$)/g
/(?:\/|^)([\w\W]*?\d)(?=\/\d|$)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AJsiBV/1). Your value is in Group 1. The regex with `[\w\W]` matches across lines, too (as `.` does not match line breaks by default).

*Details*:

- `(?:\/|^)` - a non-capturing group that matches either `/` or start of string
- `(.*?\d)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars (here, other than line break chars) as few as possible, and then a digit
- `(?=\/\d|$)` - a location that is immediately followed with `/` + digit, or end of string.

In JavaScript, you can either use `const matches = Array.from(text.matchAll(/(?:\/|^)(.*?\d)(?=\/\d|$)/g), x => x[1])`, or - if you cannot use this syntax - a more verbose legacy extraction like

```js
var s = "4d6/2d6/1d6";
var re = /(?:\/|^)(.*?\d)(?=\/\d|$)/g;
var matches=[], m;
while(m=re.exec(s)) {
  matches.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(matches)
```